# Error with FullScreenCover in SwiftUI: A new orientation transaction token is being requested while a valid one already exists

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios16, swiftui-navigationstack

I'm encountering an error when using the **`fullScreenCover`** modifier in SwiftUI. The error message states:

> "A new orientation transaction token is being requested while a valid one already exists."

The error occurs during a fullscreen transition when dismissing the current view and presenting a new view (**`fromVC`** and **`toVC`** references are provided in the error message). The window and scene orientations are both set to portrait, and there is an existing active orientation transaction token with the original orientation also set to portrait.

I have tried various solutions, including setting the **`windowOrientation`** and **`sceneOrientation`** explicitly, wrapping the **`fullScreenCover`** in a **`NavigationStack`**, and dismissing the current view using **`presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()`** when the new view is presented. However, the error persists.

This is my code:

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseAuth

@available(iOS 16.0, *)
struct SignUp: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModal = SignViewData()
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @State private var mainView = false
    @State private var SignInView = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading){
                Text("Sign Up")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundStyle(.linearGradient(colors: [.pink.opacity(0.6), .primary.opacity(0.5)], startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing))
                    .padding(.leading,10)
                    .padding(.bottom,20)
                Section{
                    TextField("", text: $viewModal.text)
                        .textContentType(.emailAddress)
                        .keyboardType(.emailAddress)
                        .autocapitalization(.none)
                        .disableAutocorrection(true)
                        .placeholder(when: viewModal.text.isEmpty) {
                            Text("Email address")
                                .foregroundColor(.primary)
                                .blendMode(.overlay)
                        }
                        .customField(icon: "envelope.open.fill")
                    SecureField("", text: $viewModal.password)
                        .textContentType(.password)
                        .placeholder(when: viewModal.password.isEmpty) {
                            Text("Password")
                                .foregroundColor(.primary)
                                .blendMode(.overlay)
                        }
                        .customField(icon: "key.fill")
                    
                }
                .padding(.leading,10)
                .padding(.trailing,10)
                .padding(.bottom,10)
                
                Button {
                    Task{
                        do{
                            try await viewModal.signUp()
                            if viewModal.value == true{
                                DispatchQueue.main.async { // Add DispatchQueue.main.async block
                                    mainView.toggle()
                                }
                            }
                            return
                        }
                        catch {
                            print(error)
                        }
                    }
                } label: {
                    ButtonView(title: "Create Account")
                }
                .padding(.leading,10)
                .padding(.trailing,10)
                .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $mainView) {
// Any time i segue into this view i keep getting the error down below
                    NavigationStack{
                        RootView()
                    }
                }
                Divider()
                    .padding(5)
                    .padding(.leading,10)
                    .padding(.trailing,10)
                HStack{
                    Text("Already have an account?")
                        .font(.subheadline)
                        .foregroundStyle(.linearGradient(colors: [.pink.opacity(0.7), .primary.opacity(0.5)], startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing))
                    Button {
                        SignInView.toggle()
                    } label: {
                        Text("Sign In")
                            .font(.subheadline)
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }
                }
                .fullScreenCover(isPresented:$SignInView){
                    NavigationStack{
                        SignIn()
                    }
                }
                .padding(.leading,20)
            }.padding(15)
                .frame(width: 400,height: 370)
                .background(.ultraThinMaterial, in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30, style: .continuous))
                .shadow(color: Color("Shadow").opacity(0.3), radius: 10, x: 0, y: 10)
                .strokeStyle(cornerRadius: 30)
                .padding(20)
        }.background(
            Image("Background 4")
        )
    }
}

@available(iOS 16.0, *)
struct SignUp_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SignUp()
    }
}

extension View {
    func placeholder<Content: View>(
        when shouldShow: Bool,
        alignment: Alignment = .leading,
        @ViewBuilder placeholder: () -> Content) -> some View {
            ZStack(alignment: alignment) {
                placeholder().opacity(shouldShow ? 1 : 0)
                self
            }
        }
}
```

full error message:

> 2023-06-10 21:37:10.137760+0300 SignEase[50521:19426350] [Assert]
> A new orientation transaction token is being requested while a valid
> one already exists. reason=Fullscreen transition (dismissing):
> fromVC=<_TtGC7SwiftUI29PresentationHostingControllerVS_7AnyView_:
> 0x13b80f200>;
> toVC=<_TtGC7SwiftUI29PresentationHostingControllerVS_7AnyView_:
> 0x13a8d7c00>;; windowOrientation=portrait; sceneOrientation=portrait;
> existingTransaction=<_UIForcedOrientationTransactionToken:
> 0x280b814a0; state: active; originalOrientation: portrait (1)>

Comment: Hi @Lawal Abdulganiy, have you a fix for the pop up error?